# thread main exiting due to uncaught exception in jpct game engine

Tags: java, android, jpct

I am trying to run a demo of JPCT. But run time error is happening. My code is below.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package com.JPCTDemo;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.threed.jpct.Camera;
import com.threed.jpct.Config;
import com.threed.jpct.FrameBuffer;
import com.threed.jpct.Light;
import com.threed.jpct.Loader;
import com.threed.jpct.Logger;
import com.threed.jpct.Object3D;
import com.threed.jpct.RGBColor;
import com.threed.jpct.SimpleVector;
import com.threed.jpct.Texture;
import com.threed.jpct.TextureManager;
import com.threed.jpct.World;
import com.threed.jpct.util.MemoryHelper;

public class JPCTDemo extends Activity {

// Used to handle pause and resume...
private static JPCTDemo master = null;

private GLSurfaceView mGLView;
private MyRenderer renderer = null;
private FrameBuffer fb = null;
private World world = null;
private int move = 0;
private float turn = 0;
private RGBColor back = new RGBColor(50, 50, 100);

private float touchTurn = 0;
private float touchTurnUp = 0;

private float xpos = -1;
private float ypos = -1;

private Texture planeReplace = null;

private Object3D plane = null;
private Object3D tree2 = null;
private Object3D tree1 = null;
private Object3D grass = null;
private Texture font = null;

private Object3D box = null;
private Object3D rock = null;

private Light sun = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Logger.log("onCreate");

    if (master != null) {
        copy(master);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(getApplication());

    mGLView.setEGLConfigChooser(new GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser() {
        public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display) {
            // Ensure that we get a 16bit framebuffer. Otherwise, we'll fall
            // back to Pixelflinger on some device (read: Samsung I7500)
            int[] attributes = new int[] { EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
            EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
            int[] result = new int[1];
            egl.eglChooseConfig(display, attributes, configs, 1, result);
            return configs[0];
        }
    });

    renderer = new MyRenderer();
    mGLView.setRenderer(renderer);
    setContentView(mGLView);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Logger.log("onPause");
    super.onPause();
    mGLView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Logger.log("onResume");
    super.onResume();
    mGLView.onResume();
}

protected void onStop() {
    Logger.log("onStop");
    super.onStop();
}

private void copy(Object src) {
    try {
        Logger.log("Copying data from master Activity!");
        Field[] fs = src.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fs) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(this, f.get(src));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        xpos = me.getX();
        ypos = me.getY();
        return true;
    }

    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        xpos = -1;
        ypos = -1;
        touchTurn = 0;
        touchTurnUp = 0;
        return true;
    }

    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        float xd = me.getX() - xpos;
        float yd = me.getY() - ypos;

        xpos = me.getX();
        ypos = me.getY();

        touchTurn = xd / 100f;
        touchTurnUp = yd / 100f;
        return true;
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(15);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Doesn't matter here...
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(me);
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
        move = 2;
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        move = -2;
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
        turn = 0.05f;
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
        turn = -0.05f;
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, msg);
}

public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
        move = 0;
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        move = 0;
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
        turn = 0;
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
        turn = 0;
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
        TextureManager.getInstance().replaceTexture("grassy", planeReplace);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, msg);
}

protected boolean isFullscreenOpaque() {
    return true;
}

class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private int fps = 0;
    private int lfps = 0;

    private long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private boolean stop = false;

    private SimpleVector sunRot = new SimpleVector(0, 0.05f, 0);

    public MyRenderer() {
        Config.maxPolysVisible = 500;
        Config.farPlane = 1500;
        Config.glTransparencyMul = 0.1f;
        Config.glTransparencyOffset = 0.1f;
        Config.useVBO=true;

        Texture.defaultToMipmapping(true);
        Texture.defaultTo4bpp(true);
    }

    public void stop() {
        stop = true;
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        if (fb != null) {
            fb.dispose();
        }

        fb = new FrameBuffer(gl, w, h);

        if (master == null) {
            world = new World();
            Resources res = getResources();

            TextureManager tm = TextureManager.getInstance();

            Texture grass2 = new Texture(res.openRawResource(R.raw.grassy));
            Texture leaves = new Texture(res.openRawResource(R.raw.tree2y));
            Texture leaves2 = new Texture(res.openRawResource(R.raw.tree3y));
            Texture rocky = new Texture(res.openRawResource(R.raw.rocky));
            Texture planetex = new Texture(res.openRawResource(R.raw.planetex));

            planeReplace = new Texture(res.openRawResource(R.raw.rocky));
            font = new Texture(res.openRawResource(R.raw.numbers));
            font.setMipmap(false);

            tm.addTexture("grass2", grass2);
            tm.addTexture("leaves", leaves);
            tm.addTexture("leaves2", leaves2);
            tm.addTexture("rock", rocky);
            tm.addTexture("grassy", planetex);

            plane = Loader.loadSerializedObject(res.openRawResource(R.raw.serplane));
            rock = Loader.loadSerializedObject(res.openRawResource(R.raw.serrock));
            tree1 = Loader.loadSerializedObject(res.openRawResource(R.raw.sertree1));
            tree2 = Loader.loadSerializedObject(res.openRawResource(R.raw.sertree2));
            grass = Loader.loadSerializedObject(res.openRawResource(R.raw.sergrass));

            grass.translate(-45, -17, -50);
            grass.rotateZ((float) Math.PI);
            rock.translate(0, 0, -90);
            rock.rotateX(-(float) Math.PI / 2);
            tree1.translate(-50, -92, -50);
            tree1.rotateZ((float) Math.PI);
            tree2.translate(60, -95, 10);
            tree2.rotateZ((float) Math.PI);
            plane.rotateX((float) Math.PI / 2f);
            plane.setName("plane");
            tree1.setName("tree1");
            tree2.setName("tree2");
            grass.setName("grass");
            rock.setName("rock");

            world.addObject(plane);
            world.addObject(tree1);
            world.addObject(tree2);
            world.addObject(grass);
            world.addObject(rock);

            plane.strip();
            tree1.strip();
            tree2.strip();
            grass.strip();
            rock.strip();

            grass.setTransparency(10);
            tree1.setTransparency(40);
            tree2.setTransparency(40);

            RGBColor dark = new RGBColor(100, 100, 100);
            tree1.setAdditionalColor(dark);
            tree2.setAdditionalColor(dark);
            grass.setAdditionalColor(dark);

            world.setAmbientLight(20, 20, 20);
            world.buildAllObjects();

            sun = new Light(world);
            sun.setIntensity(250, 250, 250);

            Camera cam = world.getCamera();
            cam.moveCamera(Camera.CAMERA_MOVEOUT, 250);
            cam.moveCamera(Camera.CAMERA_MOVEUP, 100);
            cam.lookAt(plane.getTransformedCenter());

            SimpleVector sv = new SimpleVector();
            sv.set(plane.getTransformedCenter());
            sv.y -= 300;
            sv.x -= 100;
            sv.z += 200;
            sun.setPosition(sv);

            MemoryHelper.compact();

            if (master == null) {
                Logger.log("Saving master Activity!");
                master = JPCTDemo.this;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Logger.log("onSurfaceCreated");
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        try {
            if (!stop) {
                Camera cam = world.getCamera();
                if (turn != 0) {
                    world.getCamera().rotateY(-turn);
                }

                if (touchTurn != 0) {
                    world.getCamera().rotateY(touchTurn);
                    touchTurn = 0;
                }

                if (touchTurnUp != 0) {
                    world.getCamera().rotateX(touchTurnUp);
                    touchTurnUp = 0;
                }

                if (move != 0) {
                    world.getCamera().moveCamera(cam.getDirection(), move);
                }

                fb.clear(back);
                world.renderScene(fb);
                world.draw(fb);
                blitNumber(lfps, 5, 5);

                fb.display();

                if (box != null) {
                    box.rotateX(0.01f);
                }

                if (sun != null) {
                    sun.rotate(sunRot, plane.getTransformedCenter());
                }

                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000) {
                    lfps = fps;
                    fps = 0;
                    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                fps++;
            } else {
                if (fb != null) {
                    fb.dispose();
                    fb = null;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.log("Drawing thread terminated!", Logger.MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    private void blitNumber(int number, int x, int y) {
        if (font != null) {
            String sNum = Integer.toString(number);

            for (int i = 0; i < sNum.length(); i++) {
                char cNum = sNum.charAt(i);
                int iNum = cNum - 48;
                fb.blit(font, iNum * 5, 0, x, y, 5, 9, FrameBuffer.TRANSPARENT_BLITTING);
                x += 5;
            }
        }
    }
}

 }
```

My logcat error is

```
07-10 16:01:48.679: E/dalvikvm(1417): Could not find class 'com.threed.jpct.RGBColor', referenced from method com.JPCTDemo.JPCTDemo.<init>
07-10 16:01:48.690: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): java.lang.VerifyError: com.JPCTDemo.JPCTDemo
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
07-10 16:01:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 16:01:48.709: E/dalvikvm(1417): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Thanks advance for help

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that, it couldn't find the class `com.threed.jpct.RGBColor`. I suggest to check your Build Path Configuration to see whether `jpct_ae.jar` is checked or not.

Rebuild your app and try again.